# Laravel - unexpected output with DB

Tags: php, laravel, types

I have weird problem. 
I have dynamically created tables. That's why I'm using DB

```
$spec = DB::table($specjalizacja)->where('pacjent_id','=', $pid)->orderBy('created_at')->get();
```

It returns something a collection of arrays:

```
dd($spec):
Collection {#257 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#262 ▼
      +"id": "3"
      +"pacjent_id": "1"
      +"wizyta_id": "5"
      +"a": "111"
      +"b": "abcdefg"
      +"c": "3"
      +"created_at": "2017-05-15 14:41:53"
      +"updated_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    }
    1 => {#254 ▼
      +"id": "4"
      +"pacjent_id": "1"
      +"wizyta_id": "6"
      +"a": "2222222"
      +"b": "ddddddddd"
      +"c": "3"
      +"created_at": "2017-05-15 14:41:58"
      +"updated_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is that it's not similar to datatype that Model instance is returning. F.e

```
$wizyty = Kolejka::where('data','LIKE',$dzis.'%')->where('odbyta','=','0')->where('lekarz_id','=',session('id'))->orderBy('data')->get();

dd($poprzednia):
Collection {#264 ▼
#items: array:2 [▼
0 => Kolejka {#274 ▼
  +fillable: array:30 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:10 [▼
    "id" => "5"
    "lekarz_id" => "1"
    "pacjent_id" => "1"
    "data" => "2017-05-15 11:00:00"
    "odbyta" => "1"
    "leki" => null
    "uwagi" => null
    "specjalizacja" => "1"
    "created_at" => "2017-05-15 09:52:18"
    "updated_at" => "2017-05-15 09:52:33"
  ]
  #original: array:10 [▶]
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #events: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
1 => Kolejka {#275 ▶}
]
}
```

Now in my view I can do something like that:

```
@foreach($poprzednia as $pw)
  {{$pw}}
@endforeach
```

But if I do

```
@foreach($spec as $sp)
  {{$sp}}
@endforeach
```

Or anything like trying to get value by doing $sp[0] or anything basically I am unsuccessful and end up with an error of `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

{{$spec}} in view: (doesnt work)

```
[{"id":"3","pacjent_id":"1","wizyta_id":"5","a":"111","b":"abcdefg","c":"3","created_at":"2017-05-15 14:41:53","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"id":"4","pacjent_id":"1","wizyta_id":"6","a":"2222222","b":"ddddddddd","c":"3","created_at":"2017-05-15 14:41:58","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}]
```

{{$poprzednia}} in view (that works)

```
[{"id":5,"lekarz_id":"1","pacjent_id":"1","data":"2017-05-15 11:00:00","odbyta":"1","leki":null,"uwagi":null,"specjalizacja":"1","created_at":"2017-05-15 09:52:18","updated_at":"2017-05-15 09:52:33"},{"id":6,"lekarz_id":"1","pacjent_id":"1","data":"2017-05-15 11:15:00","odbyta":"1","leki":"x","uwagi":"d","specjalizacja":"1","created_at":"2017-05-15 09:52:53","updated_at":"2017-05-15 09:53:31"}]
```

Comment: Try to `dd($sp[0]->a)`

Comment: The different here: `DB::table($specjalizacja)` And `Kolejka::where`. One is DB Query and one is Laravel Query Builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access the collection object inside the loop the same way for both the output.

```
@foreach($spec as $sp)
  {{ $sp->id }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: That seems to be working just fine. The problem I have now is how can i possibly access all this data if i do not know how columns are named? Can I somehow print all of it? Or access it by index?

Comment: Try `{{ $sp->all() }}`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying use the function of php `json_decode()` You just need to do this:

```
{{ json_decode($spec) }}
```

or in the foreach

```
@foreach($spec as $sp)
  {{ json_decode($sp) }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thats is strange. Can you try to convert the collection in to array using this function `$spec->toArray()`